# all method in while loop python

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

I have to write a function that will be executed as long as the while loop is true. The condition for this while loop is that there may be no zeros in my list. But if my list contains an element that is not zero and all the other element are zero, this is not a problem.
I'll give an example: [0, 0, 0] -> stop execution; 
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0] -> continue execution

This is my code:

```
while all(char != 0 for char in list):
list = next(list)
finallist.append(list)
```

(next is the name of my function)

Thank you

Comment: Is the condition no zeroes? Or not only zeroes? That's two very different things.

Comment: Use `.index()`?

Answer (score 1):

Your wording is confusing because it seems like you're asking for contradictory conditions, but based off of your example, I believe what you want is to have at least one non-zero in your list. In which case the answer is simply to replace `all` with `any` in your code.

Also, I would avoid naming your function `next`, as that conflicts with the `next` function that is built into Python.

Comment: I'll try to re-explain it.
1) I speak Dutch, so I translated my function 'volgende' into 'next' to make things clear.
2) Perhaps I forgot that if my list contains no zeros, my function has to execute as well, so the any() method won't work. This condition causes that the function won't work on a list like this one: [1, 2, 3]. The only list that has to return False in the while loop, is a list that only contains zeros.

Comment: What are you talking about? The `any` function would work just fine in this case. Try typing `any(char != 0 for char in [1,2,3])` in a Python interpretter. The result is `True`. Unless I'm misunderstanding you and you're saying you want at least one non-zero AND at least one zero in the list, in which case just duplicate that expression, change `!=` to `==`, and join them with `and`.

Answer (score 0):

Filter the list from zeroes:

```
[x for x in your_list if x != 0]
```

Then, check if the length of the filtered list is greater than 0 (or just put it in a condition, cause empty lists are `False` and non-empty lists are `True`:

```
while [x for x in your_list if x != 0]:
    # Do stuff
```

**Edit**: I re-read your question, and found where you were wrong,

Where using `all()`, you check that the list contains **only** elements that are not 0, while you actually have to check if that list has **any** elements that are not 0. For that, use `any()` and not <s>`all()`</s>.